# How to check if two equations are equivalent in SymPy?

Tags: sympy

Is there a comparison method to check that `sympy.Eq(expr1, expr2)` is equivalent to `sympy.Eq(expr3, expr4)`?

For example, `sympy.Eq(tan(x)*x**2 - y**2, tan(x)*x + 2*y**2)` and `sympy.Eq(-3cos(x)*y**2, sin(x)*(-x**2 + x))`.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent? Also is there any restriction on what kind of expressions would be involved in the equations? (Probably what you are asking for is algorithmically undecidable if there are no restrictions.)

Comment: A few examples would help to clarify what you mean.

Comment: You still need to give more context here about what restrictions there are in the input and what you mean by equivalence. In your example just subtracting the rhs from the lhs gives the same result for both equations: is that all you need?

Comment: My first example was too simple, I just updated it. I'm interested in the general case where the lhs - rhs for both equations are not identical, but are equal to each other.

Comment: You need to take some to think this through properly and define what you actually want clearly in words. The `lhs-rhs` of the two equations shown are not equal to each other. Also I repeat: most likely what you want is mathematically impossible without any restriction on the types of expressions involved (see Richardon's Theorem). You need to define somehow a restricted class of possible expressions or otherwise you are asking for something impossible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to is

```
eq1 = sympy.Eq(expr1, expr2)
eq2 = sympy.Eq(expr3, expr4)
assert (abs(eq1.lhs - eq1.rhs)).equals(abs(eq2.lhs - eq2.rhs))
```